# Binds same data to all children li items on ng-click

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

What I tried:-

```
  <ul id="leftMenu">
            <li ng-repeat="(networkKey, networkValue) in menuValue track by $index">
               <a href="#" ng-click="divVerticalMenuClickEventHandler($event, networkValue, 'NetworkLevel', '')">
                    Network {{$index+1}}<span> </span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="(deviceAccessPointKey, deviceAccessPointValue) in deviceAccessPointItems track by $index">
                      <a href="#" ng-click="divVerticalMenuClickEventHandler($event, networkValue +'/' +deviceAccessPointValue.name , 'DeviceLevel', deviceAccessPointValue.ref)">{{capitalizeFirstLetter(deviceAccessPointValue.name)}}<span> </span></a>
                         <div ng-repeat="(objectkey, objectValue) in objectListItems">
                            <ul class="" style="">
                             <li ng-repeat="(objectListKey, objectListValue) in objectValue track by $index | orderBy:sortMenu">
                               <a href="#"  ng-click="divVerticalMenuClickEventHandler($event, objectListValue, 'ObjectListLevel', '')">{{GetUpdatedObjectname(objectListValue)}}<span> </span>            
                               </a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Controller binds this menu dynamically.

```
 $scope.menuItems = payload.data;
```

On li item click, I call REST API and binds that li item children's. But it is binding same li items to all parent li items.
**What is Problem:-** 
**Menu Example:-**

[image]

Here the issue is, if I click on "Network1", then ***it binds both the children's of Network1 and Network2 with same data* and same happens with Devices**. If I click on Devices, then it binds Devices objects as well as Devices2 objects.

Please let me know the solution..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try ng-click="yourfunc();$event.stopPropagation()". It's a event bubbling issue as far i can see

Comment: I tried that, but it is not working. If we check the HTML code, you can see "deviceAccessPointItems" JSON object, and this object is assigned to all the li items under Network level.  So, If I click on Network1 then same "deviceAccessPointItems" is used by Network1 childres and Network2 childs. Hence It creates children items for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created one JSON object for whole menu and updating this object on menu's and sub-menu's click. I'm will be updating this menu JSON object for all the REST calls for it's childrens and will play with this object only.